# Trigger.io Toolkit 'getaddrinfo failed' with Reload - spinner stuck

Tags: reload, trigger.io

I'm trying to 'reload' my mobile app with Trigger.io Reload.

After pushing to a stream or restoring a config on the reload tab the toolkit gets stuck on 'Loading' with the spinner, and occasionally I see this error. The only way to continue is to re-open the toolkit.

```
Error in remote call to api.get: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed Details Close
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Meirion\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\async.py", line 96, in run
    result = self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Meirion\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\trigger\api\api.py", line 6, in get
    return forge_tool.singleton.remote._api_get(method, cookies=cookies)
  File "C:\Users\Meirion\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\remote.py", line 265, in _api_get
    resp = self.__get_or_post(absolute_url, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Meirion\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge\remote.py", line 221, in __get_or_post
    resp = getattr(self.session, method.lower())(url, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\Meirion\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge-dependencies\requests\sessions.py", line 254, in get
    return self.request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Meirion\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge-dependencies\requests\sessions.py", line 241, in request
    r.send(prefetch=prefetch)
  File "C:\Users\Meirion\AppData\Local\Trigger Toolkit\build-tools\forge-dependencies\requests\models.py", line 634, in send
    raise ConnectionError(sockerr)
ConnectionError: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've not been able to resolve DNS here - are you having connection problems with other programs / are you seeing similar behaviour in different locations?

We'll do a better job of making fatal errors like that more graceful in the future!

Comment: Everything else was working fine, wasn't seeing issues in any other applications. Not had the DNS error for a while though, so perhaps it was isolated, and you know about the stuck on spinner issue.